# Remove dots in dataset and split data into equal bands

Tags: r, package

My dataset has more than 200 variables and most of them have dots which indicate missing values:

Age
19
20
.
56
23

R will recognize dots as Null values. So when I use

```
> library(Hmisc) # cut2
> split(data, cut2(data$Age, g=3))
```

to divide data into 3 bands, I got error message:

Error in if (cj == upper) next : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition:  Warning messages:
1: In cut2(data2$Household_Count, g = 10) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In Ops.factor(x, (lower - min.dif.factor * min.dif)) : not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(x, (lower - min.dif.factor * min.dif)) : not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(x, (lower - min.dif.factor * min.dif)) : not meaningful for factors
5: In Ops.factor(x, (lower - min.dif.factor * min.dif)) : not meaningful for factors
6: In Ops.factor(x, (lower - min.dif.factor * min.dif)) : not meaningful for factors
7: In Ops.factor(x, (lower - min.dif.factor * min.dif)) : not meaningful for factors
8: In Ops.factor(x, (lower - min.dif.factor * min.dif)) : not meaningful for factors
9: In Ops.factor(x, (lower - min.dif.factor * min.dif)) : not meaningful for factors

I have confirmed that this error is caused by Null values. However, since I have too many variables with dots in different rows, I cannot simply get rid of dots by filtering. How can I get rid of dots and execute "splitting" command to every variable?

Comment: Convert your "dataset" to numeric. You currently have it as factor. Try `as.numeric(as.character(x))`.

Comment: If you read the data in with `read.csv` or `read.table`, you may want to set `na.strings = "."`, then you'll have `NA`s instead of `.`s in your data, which are easier to deal with in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `complete.cases` to remove NA or missing values before using `cut`. See `?complete.cases`

Example:

```
y <- airquality[,  1]
yy<-y[complete.cases(y)]
yyy<-cut(yy,3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfect!!!!! Now R has no problem executing splitting command and it also label missing values as NA.